# Foursquare API mayorships are always empty?

Tags: api, foursquare

Did anyone know why I'm always getting an empty response for the mayorship of a venue? Say I perform a request like this

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/51a2445e5019c80b56934c75
```

I don't get the actual mayor of this place. However, according to this https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/details it should be in the venues response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got it. You have to add the param for swarm-style response. So the actual request should look like this:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/51a2445e5019c80b56934c75?m=swarm
```